# Merge multiple python pandas data frames into an SQL database using sqlalchemy (postgresql)

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, dataframe, csv

I have a `postgresql` database which I am accessing using `sqlalchemy` in python.

I am trying to create a database which are made of a bunch of csv files or data frames.

The csv files look like this, there are around 20,000 of them, some of them have

`Data1.csv`

```
Date         Data1
01-Jan-2000  122.1
...
09-Oct-2020  991.2
```

`Data2.csv`

```
Date         Data2
01-Feb-2010  101.1
...
09-Oct-2020  331.2
```

`Data3.csv`

```
Date         Data3a  Data3b Data3c.....
15-Dec-2015  1125.2 ....
...
09-Oct-2020  35512.2 ....
```

```
...
...
```

`Data20000.csv`

So I am do the following,

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy
import psycopg2

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('postgresql://user@127.0.0.1',isolation_level='AUTOCOMMIT')

engine.execute('CREATE DATABASE testdb')

df = pd.read_csv("/Users/user/Documents/data/Data1.csv",index_col=0)
df.to_sql('temp',con=engine,if_exists='replace')
```

I can see that this creates an empty database called `testdb` and a table called `temp`.

How do I merge the `temp` table into the `testdb` table, so that I can create a for loop and make a table like this

```
Date Data1 Data2 Data3a Data3b Data3c
....
....
```

if I was using pandas, I would do this,

```
testdb = pd.DataFrame()
df = pd.read_csv("/Users/user/Documents/data/Data1.csv",index_col=0)
testdb = pd.merge(testdb,df,how='outer',left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

I tried `engine.execute('SELECT * from df OUTER JOIN testdb')`,

but I get the following error

```
ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError) syntax error at or near "OUTER"
LINE 1: SELECT * from df OUTER JOIN testdb
                           ^

[SQL: SELECT * from df OUTER JOIN testdb]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/f405)
```

What is the right way to merge my data here?

Update:

So I have 1389 files in this directory,
each one is around 15 years worth of daily data x 8 columns

I try to append but around 300 files in, it slows down like crazy.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
frame = pd.DataFrame()

length = len(os.listdir(filepath))
for filename in os.listdir(filepath):
    file_path = os.path.join(filepath, filename)
    print(length,end=" ")
    df = pd.read_csv(file_path,index_col=0)
    df = pd.concat([df[[col]].assign(Source=f'{filename[:-4]}-{col}').rename(columns={col: 'Data'}) for col in df])
    frame = frame.append(df)
    length-=1
```

Comment: Rather than store the data in your tabular format, I would just use a table three columns: `Date`, `Data` and `Source`.

Comment: but I need it to be in that format for when I want to extract certain columns to do data analysis on using pandas, also one date will have so many datapoints, but if I do it your way, I won't be able to see that

Comment: `SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE Source in ('Data1', 'Data2')`, then pivot the result in pandas.

Comment: how do I insert my 20,000 tables in your format then? Is there a command for that?

Comment: also, what if my source is ('Data1','Data2'...... ) where there's 5000 columns, will there be lag?

Comment: `for csv_file in file_list: pd.read_csv(csv_file, index_col=0).assign(Source=filename).to_sql('temp', if_exists='append', con=engine)`

Comment: also, lets say I create this, tomorrow Data1 gets updated, how would I replace all the data from data1 inside the table with the new Data1 set?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223131/discussion-between-alexander-and-anarchy).

Comment: hey @Alexander could you check out the update to my question, I am having an issue with speed, when I used the command you described it was really fast, but all the file names that were already already concatenated were changing retroactively. what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: That is called a quadratic copy.  You want `frame` to be a list, and then do a `pd.concat` after you loop through the files.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36489576/why-does-concatenation-of-dataframes-get-exponentially-slower

Comment: How would I go about modifying the code you showed me previously?

Comment: I checked out the link, but I’ve never see the preprocess data command before where do I get it from

Comment: hey @Alexander I decided to use SQL instead of pandas, how do I update the table? when I use if_exists='append', I get duplicates of the data when I try to update the table with the replacement csv file

Comment: First run a SQL command to delete the relevant rows, then append.

Comment: Is there a way to do like, if this exists, then delete and update , else update ?

Comment: I don't think so.  Here is where they discussed adding an upsert option to pandas `to_sql`. https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/14553

Comment: Can it be done with a combination of sql alchemy and pandas?

Comment: What’s the sql alchemy command to delete all the rows containing a certain value ?

Comment: https://towardsdatascience.com/sqlalchemy-python-tutorial-79a577141a91

Answer (score -1):

You can merge them at the dataframe level using pandas library prior to writing the records to the database table.

```py
df1 = pd.read_csv("/Users/user/Documents/data/Data1.csv",index_col=0)
df2 = pd.read_csv("/Users/user/Documents/data/Data2.csv",index_col=0)
df3 = pd.read_csv("/Users/user/Documents/data/Data3.csv",index_col=0)

final_df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], axis=1)
final_df.to_sql('temp',con=engine,if_exists='replace')
```

Comment: but, when the frame gets to 3000, the dataframe really slows down, that's why I want to create a postgresql table, like I mentioned, there's 20,000 frames, using your method, I would have to merge 20,000 frames into pandas first.

Comment: If there are 20,000 dataframes that need to be merged columnwise, it may hit postgresql's maximum number of columns (1600) per table.  

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/limits.html

Comment: is there a solution to this then? I need to store a big table so that I can easily access and update columns everyday.

Comment: Either the wider table can be broken and join whenever process the data.
Or, as user:alexander mentioned, store the data in three column format and handle them while processing.
Or Pandas can handle millions of columns (memory in the system is the hard limit). So process the data using pandas itself.